# Why recently, git rebase -i squash results in detached head

Tags: git, git-detached-head, git-interactive-rebase

Why does git rebase -i with squashes recently result in a detached head? It used to to update my current branch with the result of the interactive rebase. How do I get interactive rebase to stop going to detached HEAD?

I've always used git rebase -i to squash my commits before I pull from a remote repository to simplify handling any merge conflicts from the git pull. Instead of having to resolve conflicts over potentially multiple of my commits, I will only have to resolve one commit.

Sample command I use

```
# git rebase -i <tip of public branch> <my latest commit>
git rebase -i 380647533da 82f5ee67bed
```

After editing the rebase interactive in vim:

```
pick 3ec7c211c49 version1
s 82f5ee67bed some significant refactoring
```

Output after editting and saving the commit:

```
[detached HEAD ea50304796c] version1
 Date: Thu Jun 6 17:04:36 2019 -0400
 14 files changed, 213 insertions(+), 52 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644     some file
 create mode 100644     some file
 create mode 100644     some file
Successfully rebased and updated detached HEAD.
```

This differs from similar post
[git rebase -i develop HEAD leads to Detached Head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44177227/git-rebase-i-develop-head-leads-to-detached-head)
because the asker wants to know HOW to resolve the issue for that ONE instance. the answer is `git checkout -b branchName`. In this question, I want to know WHY it started happening recently to me and HOW to resolve it for all FUTURE instances.

This differs from the similar post [git rebase -i with squash cannot detach HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25561485/git-rebase-i-with-squash-cannot-detach-head) because the error message there is `could not detach HEAD`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [syntax guide for `git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) shows:

> `git rebase [-i | --interactive] [<options>] [--exec ] [--onto <newbase>]
>       [<upstream> [<branch>]]
>   git rebase [-i | --interactive] [<options>] [--exec <cmd>] [--onto <newbase>]
>       --root [<branch>]
>   git rebase --continue | --skip | --abort | --quit | --edit-todo | --show-current-patch`

so your command:

```
git rebase -i 380647533da 82f5ee67bed
```

is providing `380647533da` as the `<upstream>` and `82f5ee67bed` as the `<branch>`.

The first paragraph in the description section says:

> If <branch> is specified, *git rebase* will perform an automatic `git checkout <branch>` before doing anything else. Otherwise it remains on the current branch.

So, your `git rebase` is equivalent to:

```
git checkout 82f5ee67bed
git rebase 380647533da
```

The first command results in a detached HEAD.  That detached HEAD remains that way when the rebase finishes.

Comment: Ah oh. I think I had a brain fart. I mixed up the parameters I usually use with 'git diff a b' and 'git rebase -i a'. I just started vacation. I'll try again when I get back and let you know.

Comment: Just got back from vacation and tried it out. For some reason, that day I started using `git rebase -i a b` instead of just `git rebase -i a`

Answer (score 4):

I was doing:

```
git rebase -i 380647533da 82f5ee67bed
```

When I should have been doing what I always do:

```
git rebase -i 380647533da
```